# Cannot save a Custom Variational Autoencoder Model built in Keras with tensor flow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, save

Keras 2.10.0

I am trying to save my Variational Autoencoder built in Keras and Tensorflow once it is trained.
I am not being able to do so. What can I do to save the model?

Attached is the Colab link to my running  base model.

https://colab.research.google.com/github/MaxIG1/var_auto_for_synth_data/blob/saving_branch/notebooks/var_auto_working.ipynb

The error message it creates is here

> ValueError: Model <__main__.VAE object at 0x00000278F0A96E60> cannot be saved either because the input shape is not available or because the forward pass of the model is not defined.To define a forward pass, please override `Model.call()`. To specify an input shape, either call `build(input_shape)` directly, or call the model on actual data using `Model()`, `Model.fit()`, or `Model.predict()`. If you have a custom training step, please make sure to invoke the forward pass in train step through `Model.__call__`, i.e. `model(inputs)`, as opposed to `model.call()`.

Furthermore I add the main lines of code here if you do not wish to open Colab.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from keras import backend as K
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



# Creating fake data to replicate
# Define the desired number of samples for each class
class_samples = [2000, 3000, 2500, 1500]  # Adjust these numbers as needed

# Calculate weights based on the desired number of samples
class_weights = [num_samples / sum(class_samples) for num_samples in class_samples]

# Generate a synthetic dataset with different numbers of samples for each class
X, y = make_classification(
    n_samples=sum(class_samples),
    n_features=4,
    n_informative=4,
    n_redundant=0,
    n_classes=4,
    weights=class_weights,
    random_state=42,
)
columns = ["Feature_1", "Feature_2", "Feature_3", "Feature_4"]
synthetic_df = pd.DataFrame(data=X, columns=columns)
for column in synthetic_df:
    std = np.std(synthetic_df[column])
    mean = np.mean(synthetic_df[column])
    synthetic_df[column] = synthetic_df[column]-mean
    synthetic_df[column] = synthetic_df[column]/std
synthetic_df["target"] = y
synthetic_array =synthetic_df.values

# Defining the sampling layer that is also the call
class Sampling(keras.layers.Layer):

    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon

# Encoder
latent_dim = 10
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(5), name="input_layer")

n_x = 50
x = Dense(n_x, activation="relu", name="h1")(encoder_inputs)

# Split x into two halves
half_size = n_x // 2
x3_first_half = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :half_size], name="select_z_mean")(x)
x3_second_half = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, half_size:], name="select_z_var")(x)

z_mean = Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x3_first_half)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x3_second_half)
z = Sampling(name="Sampling")([z_mean, z_log_var])

encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder")
# Decoder
# Decoder
latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
n_x = 30

x = Dense(n_x, activation="relu", name="h4")(latent_inputs)

cont_decoder_outputs = Dense(4, activation="linear", name="cont_decoder_output")(x)
class_decoder_output = Dense(4, activation="softmax", name="classification_output")(x)

decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, [cont_decoder_outputs, class_decoder_output], name="decoder")
decoder.summary()
# Custom VAE
class VAE(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
        ]

    def train_step(self, data):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(data)
            reconstruction_cont, reconstruction_class = self.decoder(z)

            data_cont = data[
                :, :4
            ]  # Assuming the first 4 columns are for continuous variables
            data_class = data[:, 4:]  # Assuming the last column is for classification

            # Reconstruction loss for continuous outputs
            reconstruction_loss_cont = keras.losses.mean_squared_error(
                data_cont, reconstruction_cont
            )

            # Reconstruction loss for classification output
            reconstruction_loss_class = keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
                data_class, reconstruction_class
            )

            kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
            kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(kl_loss, axis=1)

            # Combine losses
            total_loss = (
                0.8*reconstruction_loss_cont + 0.2*reconstruction_loss_class + kl_loss
            )

        grads = tape.gradient(total_loss, self.trainable_weights)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.trainable_weights))
        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)

        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
        }

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(VAE, self).get_config()
        config.update(
            {
                "encoder": self.encoder,
                "decoder": self.decoder,
            }
        )
        return config

# Compile and Train
vae = VAE(encoder, decoder)
vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
vae.fit(
    synthetic_array,
    epochs=1,
    batch_size=16,
)

# Save in TensorFlow SavedModel format
vae.save("path_to_save_model_tf")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what to do, although it's a bit awkward in this case.

First you have to define a `call` function for your model. Add this to the `VAE` class:

```
def call(self, inputs):
    return self.decoder(self.encoder(inputs)[2])
```

This allows Keras to figure out what this model is actually supposed to do overall. It is not enough to call `fit`, because you overwrote `train_step` and it never actually calls the vae model itself, only the components (encoder and decoder).

Thus we still have to actually call the model once, so it has a defined input shape. Sprinkle this line anywhere after you defined the model, but before you try to save it:

```
vae(synthetic_array[:1])
```

This just calls the model on a single data point to define input/output shapes. After that, both saving and then loading the saved model works fine. Note that I tested this on Colab, which uses the more recent 2.15 version. I think they made some changes to saving models in the meantime, so this might not work properly on an old version.